# ExecutorService with a fixed sized thread pool - how to block any more tasks being added until the pool size has space

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, blockingqueue

My current implementation counts how many tasks are added to the pool and decrements when the complete their task.

I then tell the main code to repeat + sleep until the active tasks drop below the thread pool size before I add another task.

I feel there must be a better way?

I do not want the tasks placed in a queue, but I would happily wait for the pool to tell me it’s ready to receive more tasks.

For background, I have a web-service that I wish to invoke and it involves around 150,000 HTTP calls, I plan to do 50 at a time until the full 150,000 calls have been completed, this is why I can’t queue all tasks as I will exhaust my RAM.

I do not want any blocking to be on a timeout - I’m happy to wait as long as necessary for the thread pool to have space for new tasks.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One method to handle this is to startup your own consumer threads that run against your own `BlockingQueue`, avoiding the use of an `ExecutorService` altogether.  I.e. declare an `ArrayBlockingQueue` with capacity of 50 and have a producer thread offering/putting elements to it (which will block when the queue is full) and the consumer threads pulling from it and doing the necessary work.

Alternatively there is an implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` which does what you want by adding a custom `RejectedTaskHandler` to adding blocking behavior to the `execute` call.  See [NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor on github](https://github.com/USGS-CIDA/glri-afinch/blob/master/glri-afinch-util/src/main/java/org/java/util/concurrent/NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor.java).  I can't vouch for its quality but it should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - I'm going to try that GitHub project over the weekend, I note there's one open issue that anyone else planning on using it should bear in mind - the solution is in the issue itself anyway.